# A draggable instruction pointer during breakpoint at Xcode during runtime?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

Recently got to know that the instruction pointer that pauses execution during the breakpoint is actually draggable!

Here's an image to make things clear on what I'm talking about:-
[image: the hamburger-like thing at the pointer is what I'm talking about]

Whenever I drag the pointer(the hamburger-like thing), it just crashes (Tried it at multiple places). I understand it's a risky(as well as powerful) feature and I'm looking forward to make good use of it. I've searched answers but no luck..

Can someone make this clear for me? Any info is appreciated, thanks!

WWDC 2018 - Session 412 is where I got this from

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'd [file a Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/) if I were you.

Comment: The fact that it crashes is a bug? Or the feature itself seems like a bug?

Comment: The fact that it crashes. The feature has been around for years, but it didn't used to crash.